# Changing pointer of self

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, memory-management

I have an object that I alloc/init like normal just to get a instance. Later in my application I want to load state from disk for that object. I figure I could unarchive my class (which conforms to NSCoding) and just swap where my instance points to. To this end I use this code...

```
NSString* pathForDataFile = [self pathForDataFile];
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:pathForDataFile] == YES)
{
    NSLog(@"Save file exists");
    NSData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathForDataFile];
    NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
    [data release];

    Person *tempPerson = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"Person"];
    [unarchiver finishDecoding];
    [unarchiver release];   

    if (tempPerson)
    {
        [self release];
        self = [tempPerson retain];
    }
}
```

Now when I sprinkled some NSLogs throughout my application I noticed

```
self.person: <Person: 0x3d01a10> (After I create the object with alloc/init)
self: <Person: 0x3d01a10> (At the start of this method)
tempPerson: <Person: 0x3b1b880> (When I create the tempPerson)
self: <Person: 0x3b1b880> (after i point self to the location of the tempPerson)
self.person: <Person: 0x3d01a10> (After the method back in the main program)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`self` is a function argument to instance methods.  Assigning to self is perfectly reasonable, just like assigning values to other function arguments is perfectly reasonable.  Since the scope of `self` is the current function, your code leaks one object and releases another in a way that will most likely cause a crash.

The only time it is meaningful to assign to `self` is in an `init` method.  Although it is almost never used, `init` methods are allowed to release self and allocate a new object to return or just return nil.  The only reason this works is because the return value is self and callers of `init` expect to use the return value.

As gf pointed out, the correct approach is a load function that assigns new values to the members of your instance, not that tries to replace the instance.

Comment: Both excellent answers. This one gives me a bit more background as to why my approach was so wrong, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Don't do this. Besides that it breaks identity rules, you can't change the pointer values other parts of a program hold.

A better approach would be to use the PIMPL idiom: your class holds a pointer to an implementation object and you only swap that.

E.g. something along the lines of this:

```
@class FooImpl;
@interface Foo {
    FooImpl* impl;
}
// ...
- (void)load;
@end

@implementation Foo
- (void)load {
    FooImpl* tmp = loadFromDisk();
    if (tmp) {
        FooImpl* old = impl;
        impl = tmp;
        [old release];
    }
}
@end
```